# create tar file from stdin

Tags: pipe, tar

I want to backup mysql to a tape on-the-fly. Some like

```
mysqldump|tar --filename=mysqlbackup.sql > /dev/tape
```

I want the tape has content a tar file and this file has content "mysqldump.sql"

So a command "tar -t < /dev/tape" should output

```
mysqldump.sql
```

I don't want at first save mysqldump to file, because I have no space and IO resources. I want to do it on-the-fly.

I don't want "mysqldump > /dev/tape" because there is no metainfo and no way to know the tape has any content/

Comment: If, as you seem to want, /dev/tape *is* a tarfile with your sqldump in it, how do you know it has any content (since you couldn't know if it just has the sqldump)?

Comment: /dev/tape is not a tarfile. it is tape (magnetic film) hardware device

Comment: Sure, but if you expect `tar -t < /dev/tape` to work, its contents must *be* the contents of a tarfile.

Comment: Yes. It is easily to accomplish for a bunch of files: tar -c /home > /dev/tape    now tape contains the tar file, which may be listed by tar -t. My question is how to do it with STDIN

Comment: You still haven't answered my original question.

Comment: You can't create a tar file from stdin. Each file in the tar has a header including the length of the file, so tar has to know how much data there is before writing the header.

Comment: The file size in the tar header is a fixed length, so it could be filled with null bytes and then when the file is closed it could seek back to that location and write the file size.

Comment: This might help: [Is it possible to make a .tar.gz file directly from stdin? Or, I need to tar together already gzipped files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214542/74329)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User parkydr gave the better answer:

**You can't create a tar file from stdin**. Each file in the tar has a header including the length of the file, so tar has to know how much data there is before writing the header. –  parkydr

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of future visitors: `mysqldump` produces the single file, that’s why the most appropriate way to store it on the tape would be probably:

```
mysqldump| bzip2 - > mysqldump-`date +"%y-%b-%d"`.bz2
```