# grep output to TAR

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I know I am doing something silly here , but not able to get this working.

I need to grep a file & create a TAR file out of that grep output

```
grep -a -E '*abcdefg*|*123*|hi' test.txt | tar -czvf test.rar.gz -T -
```

command failing with below error

```
  tar\: abcdefg\t\1488877199\Link\t\thttps\\\://abcdefg//724974226928ars\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1Cannot 

stat\: No such file or directory: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
    tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: test.txt doesn't probably exist. Trying using a valid filename.

Comment: @afr0ck the test.txt did exist , I can see the grep output in the error message (now updated above)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create tar file from stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28238945/1255289)

Comment: Redirect output from the first command to a file (grep .... > output) then launch the tar command on the generated output file (do not use the pipe, instead use a semi-colon ; to seperate the two commandes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-T` argument specifies a list of files to put into the archive. That's what you're trying to provide on STDIN, not the actual data.

> -T filename
>
> In x or t mode, tar will read the list of names to be extracted from filename.  In c mode, tar will read names to be archived from filename.  The special name ''-C'' on a line by itself will cause the current directory to be changed to the directory specified on the following line.  Names are terminated by newlines unless --null is specified.  Note that --null also disables the special handling of lines containing ``-C''.

In any case, [you can't archive from STDIN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28238945/1255289). You'll need to put the data into an intermediate file first.

```
grep -a -E '*abcdefg*|*123*|hi' test.txt > tempfile
tar -czvf test.tar.gz tempfile
```

Or, just use `gzip` alone:

```
grep -a -E '*abcdefg*|*123*|hi' test.txt | gzip > test.gz
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation , now I know the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this -

```
grep -a -E '*abcdefg*|*123*|hi' test.txt > ff &&  tar -czvf test.rar.gz ff
```