# pipe input into tar while combining directory while piping to another program without temporary file

Tags: ubuntu, sh, tar

I have the following command to tar a folder while sending it to aws s3:

```
  tar czf - /path/to/folder | aws s3 cp s3://bucket.file.tar.gz
```

I would like to add output from mysqldump to the folder, but without saving the file - even temporarily - in the folder structure.

Ideally I also don't want to save the output of tar temporarily somewhere else, both for general security concerns and to save disk space.

Comment: This might help: [Is it possible to make a .tar.gz file directly from stdin? Or, I need to tar together already gzipped files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214542/74329)

Comment: Is the goal to have mysqldump in the s3 bucket tar file but under /path/to/folder/mysqldump without actually putting the file in that folder locally?

Comment: @user2199860 yes exactly

Comment: OK, see my answer below, that should do exactly that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create tar file from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238945/create-tar-file-from-stdin)

Comment: @EchoMike444 no I have that already, I want to combine stdin and file system AND have the mysqldump not saved temporarily in the folder where it finally resides in the tar.gz

Comment: the answer is you can NOT ... this is IMPOSSIBLE

Comment: @EchoMike444 yes, but as per accepted answer I can keep it out of the doc root and still have it in an easy to find location in the tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the path of a file being added to a tar file like so:

```
tar -czf - --transform=s,Downloads,var/lib, Downloads/myfile.txt > out.gz

tar -tzf out.tgz
var/lib/myfile.txt
```

Comment: I am not sure if this meets the requirement, because he wrote in his question: *I also don't want to save the output of tar temporarily somewhere*

Comment: You don't.  You just pipe to S3 instead of out.gz.  That is just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Excellent, this is not 100% achieving what I asked, but it keeps the database dump out of the document root.

Comment: Here is what I just ran: mysqldump --set-gtid-purged=OFF mysitedb > /tmp/mysitedb_20200530.sql;tar czf - --transform=s,tmp,var/www/mysite.com/htdocs, /tmp/mysitedb.sql /var/www/mysite.com/htdocs/ | /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp --storage-class STANDARD_IA  - s3://bucket/mysite.com.20200530.tar.gz